# How to customize location service using request alert

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I want to use an customized alert like the Weather app

[image: Weather]

instead of the default alert

[image]

How can i do? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` or `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` key in your `plist` file:

See below picture:

[image]

After adding these keys in your plist file remove app from device or simulator and run it.